# Executing FTP through SSIS 2008 DTEXEC method - Getting error "The Process Exit code was 1 while the expected was 0

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, sftp, ssis-2008

I have seen other posts about this topic where some of the suggestions lead people to check the ProtectionLevel to DontSaveSensitive. I have made sure that is set to DontSaveSenistive, as well as I have checked permissions and made sure where the files/dtsx files are getting called from have ample permissions set for the service account which owns the SQL Agent.

The odd thing is this process was working fine until i went into one of the previous dtsx files and had to update a datatype precision to go from a limit of 1 character to 30 characters. That was literally the only change made to the process, but now I am getting this error. I have gotten this error before, which is when I was set on the path to checking protection level and permissions/ownership. For some reason it went away and began working when i made those changes. None of that stuff (permissions/ownership) is incorrect this time around yet I am getting that same error.

Another weird thing about the process is that it is only the last step which is failing (the FTP step.) When I try to go in and execute the psftp.exe and put in the command which is being passed normally through SSIS execute process task step, the psftp.exe is telling me that the port number is incorrect..yet when I test connection on the connection manager inside VS with the exact same port, it says connection successful.

This error is vague and confusing!

I would love some guidance on some more things to try.

thank you !

Comment: Are you able to execute this in visual studio ?

Comment: Well I have been having some issues with visual studio. In the 2008 version, the play button is greyed out... and the only way I know to execute the package is to use the exectuion utility. This is the location where I am actually getting the error. When it gets exectuted via SQL Agent, it just spins and spins.

Comment: Guess u should upgrade the package, open package in new development environment. or  A quick test will be, write a bat file and execute it in windows scheduler, if it succeeds it clearly indicates permission issue

Comment: i did try to open the package in VS 2013 which i have installed on another machine, and then after i did so it says it was corrupted by the version number being 8 instead of 3. I noticed when i did that it changed the XML out entirely. My thought was to open it in 2013VS like you suggest, and then just deploy it out to sql server that way and add it to the correct step that way...but apparently I am not able to deploy the 2013 version package to SQL Server 2008R2 which is why this process stuck to using the old versions of the package.

Comment: you think I would be able to use windows scheduler to call a newer package and just have the process in two different pieces?

Comment: Yes you should do, try and test that. Do some reverse engineering, work out from there.

Comment: thank you  for the quick response!

Comment: Hello again, I attempted to do this, but I can't seem to get the correct commands in the batch file. This DTexec.exe is not doing anything. I also tried to just do a sql agent job to a file system and call the version of the package from 2013VS where I have tested and know it works, yet it gives me an error like this - "TITLE: SSIS Execution Properties
------------------------------

The package failed to load due to error 0xC0010014 "One or more error occurred. This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.

Comment: Thats good you are testing it. You should be able to get command lines, check if you have Dtexec.exe is installed. You will need exact error description, can you also deploy it to SSIS package store.Validate packages, you will get exact error description

Comment: Your question is bit confusing. 1) `psftp` is SFTP client, not FTP client. 2) On the contrary, *"connection manager inside VS"* knows FTP only, not SFTP. 3) How can `psftp` tell that *"the port number is incorrect"* - Show us the exact error message.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. Due to the fact that we have SQL Server 2008 R2 and cannot deploy SSIS (2013 version with FTP built in) packages to it, we had to use this older version of VS/SSIS/DTSX files which are 2008 version. In the VS 2008 we are using a execute process task, linked up to a FTP connection manager, and the execute process task is actually calling the PSFTP.exe and passing the parameters.

Comment: "When I try to...execute the psftp.exe and put in the command" Please [edit] your question to show the exact psftp command that you are testing, and the exact error message that you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

### SSIS tooling and version

SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 can only be edited using Visual Studio 2008 which has the Business Intelligence Design Studio templates installed. Those can only be acquired by having the physical SQL Server iso handy. Developer edition will work, but you need some form of licensed media to get BIDS working.

Visual Studio 2013 is going to attempt to upgrade 2008/R2 to the internals for a SQL Server 2012 installation. There is no going backwards/downgrading once this is done.

Any tooling (dtexec, dtutil, etc) you use must be from the same version otherwise, the first thing the binaries do is update the package to match that version. For execution (dtexec), *each* time you run a package, there is a delay as the original is upgraded in memory to match and then execution begins (assuming all goes well).  It sounds like it's not based on

> The package failed to load due to error 0xC0010014...

For deployment (dtutil), you only pay the price of upgrading once and then it's upgraded forever. Which probably isn't what you wanted. Be aware that tools like Visual Studio and SSMS "know" which version of tooling they are associated with so deploying from SSMS 2016 can result in the binaries for SQL Server 2016 SSIS upgrading your 2008 package to 2016 format and then attempting to deploy the now upgraded bits to your 2008 box. It's all very frustrating and not intuitive.

From your comment "In the 2008 version, the play button is greyed out..." That indicates you have opened a File in Visual Studio that is an SSIS package. Visual Studio will open it and paint all the icons on there but it can't actually *run* a package unless you have an Integration Services project open (and have the BI templates installed).

Assuming you have source control, you can rollback the change that broke everything and try to edit the package properly.

### Execute process task

You have an Execute Process Task that is invoking psftp.exe and it's generating a 1 versus a 0. Is that bad? Based on previous workings with SFTP clients, they're rather picky so running it as me on production would fail since I didn't have whatever bits associated to my domain account but the service account had all the right things in their profile and it would run just fine - same machine, same package, just different user.